# R ggplot2 patchwork common axis labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, patchwork

Based on the code and data below, is it possible to have common legend labels without having to remove `xlab` and `ylab` from the `ggplot` codes using `patchwork`?

The reason why I ask this is because I have lots of `ggplots` and so I don't find it ideal to remove `xlab` and `ylab` from each of the `ggplots` and then use the method in the code. I know I can use `ggarrange` but `ggpubr` is much slower than `patchwork`.

Sample data and code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)
library(gridextra)

gg1 = ggplot(mtcars) +
  aes(x = cyl, y = disp) +
  geom_point() +
  xlab("Disp") +
  ylab("Hp // Cyl") +
  theme(axis.title = element_blank())

gg2 = gg1 %+% aes(x = hp) +
  xlab("Disp") +
  ylab("Hp // Cyl")

# This method still keeps the individual axis labels.
p = gg1 + gg2
gt = patchwork::patchworkGrob(p)
gridExtra::grid.arrange(gt, left = "Disp", bottom = "Hp // Cyl")
```

Comment: Is `gg1` meant where you refer to `p1`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

###### Update

With `patchwork >= 1.2.0` it is now possible to collect the axis titles using the new `axis_title=` parameter of `plot_layout()`, i.e. similar to `guides="collect"` one can now set `axis_title="collect"` to add a shared axis titles.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

packageVersion("patchwork")
#> [1] '1.2.0'

gg1 <- ggplot(mtcars) +
  aes(x = cyl, y = disp) +
  geom_point() +
  xlab("Disp") +
  ylab("Hp // Cyl")

gg2 <- gg1 %+% aes(x = hp) +
  xlab("Disp") +
  ylab("Hp // Cyl")

gg1 + gg2 +
  plot_layout(axis_titles = "collect")
```

[image]

###### Original answer

One possible option to have a common axis title without having to remove `xlab` and `ylab` from the ggplot code would be to remove the axis labels via `& labs(...)` when creating the patch and adding a common axis title as a separate plot where I made use of `cowplot::get_plot_component` to create the axis title plot:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)
library(cowplot)


gg1 <- ggplot(mtcars) +
  aes(x = cyl, y = disp) +
  geom_point() +
  xlab("Disp") +
  ylab("Hp // Cyl") +
  theme(axis.title = element_blank())

gg2 <- gg1 %+% aes(x = hp) +
  xlab("Disp") +
  ylab("Hp // Cyl")

gg_axis <- cowplot::get_plot_component(ggplot() +
  labs(x = "Hp // Cyl"), "xlab-b")

(gg1 + gg2 & labs(x = NULL, y = NULL)) / gg_axis + plot_layout(heights = c(40, 1))
```

[image]

**UPDATE** To add a y-axis it's basically the same. To get the left y axis title we have to use `ylab-l`. Additionally, we have to add a spacer to the patch. IMHO the best approach in this case would be to put all components in a list and use the `design` argument of `plot_layout` to place them in the patch.

```
p <- ggplot() + labs(x = "Hp // Cyl", y = "Disp")
x_axis <- cowplot::get_plot_component(p, "xlab-b")
y_axis <- cowplot::get_plot_component(p, "ylab-l")

design = "
DAB
#CC
"

list(
  gg1 + labs(x = NULL, y = NULL), # A
  gg2 + labs(x = NULL, y = NULL), # B
  x_axis,# C
  y_axis # D
) |> 
  wrap_plots() + 
  plot_layout(heights = c(40, 1), widths = c(1, 50, 50), design = design)
```

Comment: Cheers, so for the `y-axis` label should I add `labs(x = "Hp // Cyl"), "xlab-b", y  = "Disp", "ylab-b"` ?

Comment: A bit more work than that. :) See my update.

Comment: Good day Stefan, the code is not seem to be working as intended with my code, the code and data is the same as in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73043424/r-ggplot2-patchwork-changes-label-location/73043626?noredirect=1#comment129009203_73043626). Should I edit my question and add the code and data here?

Answer (score 3):

You could also just make a blank plot with the label you need, then use plotlayout() with a high width ratio to combine.

```
blanklabelplot<-ggplot()+labs(y="your title")+theme_classic()+ 
  guides(x = "none", y = "none")
  
blanklabelplot+plot+ plot_layout(widths=c(1,1000))
```